# Parse jquery response (given in array)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax call, unfortunately the response arrived in an array (as it seems from firebug).

**[-Response-]:**

`$(server_response)` Jquery command gives us:

```
Object[center, br, <TextNode textContent="\n">, script jquery.js, 
<TextNode textContent="\n">, script, <TextNode textContent="\n">, 
table#megye_tablazat.tablazat, <TextNode textContent="\n\n">, 
input#response_rowid >AAAR7uAAFAAAHY5AAB, <TextNode textContent="\n">, 
input#response_status SUCCESS, <TextNode textContent="\n">]
```

I need the information of the inputs with id: `response_rowid` and `response_status`. If i use:

```
$(server_response).find('#response_rowid')
```

OR

```
$(server_response).find('#response_status')
```

It cannot found the needed element (as it seems it is searching only at the center element...), how can i find the simplest way this elements? (#response_rowid,#response_status)

Or should i iterate trough the array? and check the elemnets of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.filter()` <kbd>[jQuery API - filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)</kbd> instead of `.find()`:

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector [...].

```
$(server_response).filter('#response_status')
```

Comment: Percect, i knew before the filter command and tried it with other response, but not exactly know the basic maining. Ty.